# SQL-Server Closure table query

Tags: sql-server

I need a hierarchy for my database and decided to use the closure table model. The hierarchy tables have the usual structure, like this:

locations table

```
+----+---------+
| id |  name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Europe  |
|  2 | France  |
|  3 | Germany |
|  4 | Spain   |
|  5 | Paris   |
|  6 | Nizza   |
|  7 | Berlin  |
|  8 | Munich  |
|  9 | Madrid  |
+----+---------+

CREATE TABLE locations (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(30)
)
```

lacations_relation table

```
+----+--------+--------+-------+
| id | src_id | dst_id | depth |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
|  1 |      1 |      1 |     0 |
|  2 |      2 |      2 |     0 |
|  3 |      1 |      2 |     1 |
|  4 |      3 |      3 |     0 |
|  5 |      1 |      3 |     1 |
|  6 |      4 |      4 |     0 |
|  7 |      1 |      4 |     1 |
|  8 |      5 |      5 |     0 |
|  9 |      2 |      5 |     1 |
| 10 |      1 |      5 |     2 |
| 11 |      6 |      6 |     0 |
| 12 |      2 |      6 |     1 |
| 13 |      1 |      6 |     2 |
| 14 |      7 |      7 |     0 |
| 15 |      3 |      7 |     1 |
| 16 |      1 |      7 |     2 |
| 17 |      8 |      8 |     0 |
| 18 |      3 |      8 |     1 |
| 19 |      1 |      8 |     2 |
| 20 |      9 |      9 |     0 |
| 21 |      4 |      9 |     1 |
| 22 |      1 |      9 |     2 |
+----+--------+--------+-------+

CREATE TABLE locations_relation (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    src_id int,
    dst_id int,
    depth int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_src FOREIGN KEY (src_id)
    REFERENCES locations (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_dst FOREIGN KEY (dst_id)
    REFERENCES locations (id)
)
```

Now there is a third table, which holds information about documents and is referencing the locations table, which looks like this:

closure_junction

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | country_id | document_id |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 |          2 |           1 |
|  2 |          2 |           2 |
|  3 |          6 |           2 |
|  4 |          6 |           3 |
|  5 |          5 |           2 |
|  6 |          5 |           4 |
+----+------------+-------------+

CREATE TABLE closure_junction (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    country_id int NOT NULL,
    document_id int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_countries FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES countries(id)
)
```

What I'd like to have is single SQL-Query which counts the document per location and if there are documents in a child it should be counted up in the parent. For example if paris holds 2 documents than france should automatically also hold 2 documents. The query should also output the path of each node to the root aswell as the depth of the node. **I know there is way to do this recursively, but I'd like to avoid that.**

I have a query which gives me the correct result, but I'm not satisfied with how it works. Is there a way to circumentvent storing the children in a column?

This is my query with the correct output:

```
;WITH cte (name, path, depth, children) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        node.name, 
        STRING_AGG(locations.name, ' / ' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY relation.depth DESC) as path, 
        MAX(relation.depth) as depth,
        STRING_AGG(locations.id, ' ') as children
    FROM locations node
    INNER JOIN locations_relation relation
    ON node.id = relation.dst_id
    INNER JOIN locations
    ON relation.src_id = locations.id
    GROUP BY node.name
)
SELECT 
    name, 
    path, 
    depth,
    COUNT(DISTINCT document_id) as count_docs
 FROM cte
 CROSS APPLY string_split(children, ' ')
 LEFT JOIN closure_junction ON
   closure_junction.country_id = value
GROUP BY name, path, depth
ORDER BY depth ASC


+---------+---------------------------+-------+------------+
|  name   |           path            | depth | count_docs |
+---------+---------------------------+-------+------------+
| Europe  | Europe                    |     0 |          0 |
| France  | Europe / France           |     1 |          2 |
| Germany | Europe / Germany          |     1 |          0 |
| Spain   | Europe / Spain            |     1 |          0 |
| Berlin  | Europe / Germany / Berlin |     2 |          0 |
| Madrid  | Europe / Spain / Madrid   |     2 |          0 |
| Munich  | Europe / Germany / Munich |     2 |          0 |
| Nizza   | Europe / France / Nizza   |     2 |          3 |
| Paris   | Europe / France / Paris   |     2 |          3 |
+---------+---------------------------+-------+------------+
```

Would be great if someone could give me a clue on how to accomplish this.

Comment: If you do not store children (path) in a single colum, how do you want those appear? You can't use multiple columns unless your path has maximum depth; having used some such structures myself there is always some user, who needs deeper tree. If you decide to restrict your tree depth anyway, then you can use joins to produce all paths in separtae columns (level1 / level2 / etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count you can easily replace with a simple LEFT JOIN, but for this path you will still need to concatenate it somehow.

Something like this:

```
WITH CTE_path
AS
(   SELECT node.id,
         STRING_AGG(locations.name, ' / ' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY relation.depth DESC) as path 
    FROM locations node
    INNER JOIN locations_relation relation
    ON node.id = relation.dst_id
    INNER JOIN locations
    ON relation.src_id = locations.id
    GROUP BY node.id)
 
SELECT l.name,count(DISTINCT cj.document_id),pa.path
FROM locations l
JOIN CTE_path pa
ON pa.id = l.id
LEFT JOIN locations_relation lr
ON l.id = lr.dst_id
LEFT JOIN closure_junction cj
ON cj.country_id = lr.src_id
GROUP BY l.name,pa.path
```

Comment: Thanks, this works a lot better than my query :) I twisted my head a little on why I couldn't figure this out